# Improve Dynamic Dropdown Solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a dynamic dropdown list with jQuery and JavaScript. I'm hoping someone can take a look and let me know if this is an appropriate way to handle this type of task. I'm specifically curious to know if this code is scalable, and will it perform well? Next, would it be suggested to use a `switch` statement instead of several `if` statements in the JavaScript I have below? If so, why? I'd like to store this to be reused anytime I implement a solution like this, but as I'm new to JavaScript I don't completely trust my work yet.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/6vrpF/

**HTML**:

```
<select id='parent'>
  <option value='test'>test</option>
  <option value='sure'>sure</option>
  <option value='cool'>cool</option>
  <option value='best'>best</option>
</select>

<select id='child'>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function newDropdown()
{
   var html = ""
   for(i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
   {
     html += "<option value='"+arguments[i]+"'>"+arguments[i]+"</option>"
   }
   $("#child").append(html)
}

$("#parent").on("change",function(){
  $('#child').text("")
  var selection = $("#parent").val()
  if(selection == 'test') {newDropdown('a','b','c')}
  if(selection == 'sure') {newDropdown('d','e','f')}
  if(selection == 'cool') {newDropdown('g','h','i')}
  if(selection == 'best') {newDropdown('j','k','l')}
});
```

Comment: Well i am not confident with Jquery but, if it works well you can see when you try out.   

Imagine you have to re-use this code in different situation, I would store conditions ('test','sure'...) in an ArrayList or HashMap, then get the action an execute.  

About the switch, it is supposed to be slower and best practice, but if you use if instead, use if/else unless you WANT to pass through all conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updated the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/6vrpF/4/

```
var parentChild = {
    "test" :['a','b','c'],
    "sure" :['d','e','f'],
    "cool" :['g','h','i'],
    "best" :['j','k','l']
};

function newDropdown()
{
    var html = ""
    for(i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
    {
        html += "<option value='"+arguments[i]+"'>"+arguments[i]+"</option>"
    }
    $("#child").append(html)
}

$("#parent").on("change",function(){
    $('#child').text("")
    var selection = $("#parent").val();
    newDropdown( parentChild[selection].join(",") );
});
```

You need to get your data in the JSON format as mentioned/defined above

Edit: this is the updated fiddle which will give options one by one
http://jsfiddle.net/6vrpF/6/

```
var parentChild = {
    "test" :['a','b','c'],
    "sure" :['d','e','f'],
    "cool" :['g','h','i'],
    "best" :['j','k','l']
};

function newDropdown()
{
    var array = arguments[0];
    var html = ""
    for(i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        html += "<option value='"+array[i]+"'>"+array[i]+"</option>"
    }
    $("#child").append(html)
}

$("#parent").on("change",function(){
    $('#child').text("")
    var selection = $("#parent").val();
    newDropdown( parentChild[selection] );
});
```

Comment: The parameters you send to the newDropdown function are received as a single string, so only one option is created every time, I think you should send the actual array and iterate on that instead of the arguments.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was hoping to get out of this question. Much appreciated.

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, why not use jQuery? And why do logic in an event handler if you're just going to pass it to a function anyway? [I think I would handle it like this](http://jsfiddle.net/McS3F/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - thanks. I've been looking at your code and am trying to figure out why you pass `i` and `argVal` as arguments. Can you explain?

Comment: @fstephen07 When you utilize `$.each()` on an array you are returned two arguments, the first being the index, and the 2nd being the value of the array element at said index position.